# Not able to create resource file in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, multilingual

I'm trying to generate local resource file for pages. I successfully generated a few, but one of the pages didnt generate resource file, showing a message in output:
"Start creating resource content and adding 'meta' attributes to server controls and directives.
A resource writer could not be found.
Finished creating resource content and adding 'meta' attributes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App_LocalResources folder already existed in the parent folder but was excluded from project, hence it was not generating the resx file. All I had to do was to include the folder back into the project.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding/changing the *globalization* attribute in *web.config* and then verify.

```
<system.web>
  <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
</system.web>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: saw this in another forum, dint workout. for some pages im able to create resource files successfully.

Comment: Ok, show what are you doing exactly and for which pages it is not working.

Comment: it is just two similar kind of pages with some controls like labels,textboxes and datagrid.

Comment: well, there is already a resx file with the page along with .aspx and .aspx.cs. i think that might be the reason. how do i create resx file for lang change in this case. I tried deleting, dint work

Comment: i have to tell you one more thing, these pages were originally created in older version of VS and now converted into VS2012. Multilingual features wasnt there before, its being introduced now only.